# activemq consumer seems to "always cache"?

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I noticed with activemq (5.5) if I do this pseudocode:

```
connection = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(...)
connection.start()
session = connection.createSession(transacted=true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)
destination = session.createQueue(...)
consumer = session.createConsumer(destination)
```

That the consumer appears to grab an element from the queue, before I even request one.  Even if I do wireFormat.cacheEnabled=false

Anybody know how to prevent a consumer from "grabbing an element" by default?

Comment: What does your connect string look like? prefetch will cause that.

Comment: ?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0&wireFormat.cacheEnabled=false

Comment: Try adding `&jms.prefetchPolicy.all=0` and see if that stops it. Be aware though that prefetch isn't necessarity a bad thing: http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html

Comment: oh wow that fixed it thanks! Feel free to promote it to a real answer :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `&jms.prefetchPolicy.all=0` to your connect string and see if that stops it. The prefetch policy defaults are fairly large and I suspect that's the behavior you're seeing.

Be aware though that prefetch isn't necessarily a bad thing: http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html

Comment: true, interestingly if I *don't* use the cache it can slow activemq down quite a bit.